# How to customize vhost.conf on plesk 12.5?

Tags: apache, plesk

I should edit my `vhost.conf` for one domain on my VPS. I use plesk 12.5 on centos 7.

I should add directive:

```
ServerAlias "*.foo.bar"
```

to permit wordpress to manage multisite.

I have followed many guides, but I'm not be able to edit configuration.

I have tried to edit /var/www/vhosts/foo.bar/conf/vhost.conf , but file not exist. I have created this one and i have added directive. After that i have launched:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
service httpd restart
```

But Plesk ignore this file.

I have even tried to add directive on `Plesk > Subscription > domain.tld > Apache & Nginx Settings (http and https)`, but plesk still ignoring me.

Any hint to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of nginx corresponded derictives should be added not only in `vhost.conf` but in `vhost_nginx.conf` as well (note for **system** folder):

```
# for apache
printf '\nServerAlias "*.foo.bar"\n' >> /var/www/vhosts/system/foo.bar/conf/vhost.conf
chgrp apache /var/www/vhosts/system/foo.bar/conf/vhost.conf

# for nginx
printf '\nserver_name *.foo.bar;\n' >> /var/www/vhosts/system/foo.bar/conf/vhost_nginx.conf
chgrp nginx /var/www/vhosts/system/foo.bar/conf/vhost_nginx.conf
```

Same for `Plesk > Subscription > foo.bar > Apache & Nginx Settings` (http and http**s** and **nginx**)